# Print Multiple PDFs Using Different Layers Using a QGIS 3.0 Layout

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, print-composer

I have an open QGIS 3.0 project with a layout called "plan_view1".  There are numerous selected layers (>100) that I want to turn on one-by-one and print the "plan_view1" layout to a pdf.

This is my code:

```
def printpdfmulti(layoutname):
    selected_layers = qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
    projectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
    layoutmanager = projectInstance.layoutManager()
    layout = layoutmanager.layoutByName(layoutname) #Layout nameprojectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
    for layer in selected_layers:
        qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, True)
        exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
        exporter.exportToPdf("C://data//" + layer.name() + ".pdf", QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings() )
        qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, False)


printpdfmulti("plane_view1")
```

The error messsage I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 7, in printpdfmulti
AttributeError: 'QgisInterface' object has no attribute 'legendInterface'
```

What have I done wrong?
I know my python programming is still very rough on the edges.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following line:

```
qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, True)
```

with this:

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(True)
```

---

And to switch the visibility off, replace `True` with `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Joseph.

I made your suggested changes and I also made 2 other changes:

1. Refresh: a layout.refresh() updated the legend
2. File Name Cleanup:  I removed any problem characters from the layer names so they would be valid filenames

Thanks for the help.
The final working code is below.

```
def printpdfmulti(layoutname):
    selected_layers = qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
    projectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
    layoutmanager = projectInstance.layoutManager()
    layout = layoutmanager.layoutByName(layoutname) #Layout nameprojectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
    for layer in selected_layers:
        QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(True)
        layout.refresh()
        exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
        filename = "".join(i for i in layer.name() if i not in "\/:*?<>|")
        exporter.exportToPdf("C://data//" + filename + ".pdf", QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings() )
        QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)


printpdfmulti("plane_view1")
```